# ImageMagickで、画像に、円弧に沿って文字列を描画できますか？

Tags: imagemagick

ImageMagickで、画像に、円弧に沿って文字列を描画する方法はありますか？

SVGのtextPathを使用すればできるのでは？ と思ったのですが、
[ImageMagickではSVGのtextPathが使えない](https://blog.osakana.net/archives/8954)と書いてあり、他の方法を思いつかないので質問しました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この記事 [ImageMagick Examples -- Compound Font Effects](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/fonts/#arch) の Circle Font の項目とか。そこに紹介されている記事 [ImageMagick Examples -- Distorting Images](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#arc) の Arc into Full Circle Rings の項目あたりでは？

Comment: まだ試行錯誤している途中ですが、「Arc 360」指定するとやりたいことができそうです(円弧に沿って文字が描画されました)。大変参考になりました